# How do I get back to the running instance of riak-shell?

Tags: riak

I was in riak-shell when ssh lost its connection to the server. After reconnecting, I do the following:

```
sudo riak-shell
```

and get:

```
An instance of riak-shell is already running
```

So, I restarted the riak node in question. This did not seem to solve the problem. I do not see anything using `ps -aux` to kill. According to the docs, only one instance can run at a time. That makes sense, but when I run riak-shell from another node and try to connect to any node, I now get the following:

```
Error: invalid function call : connection_EXT:connect ["riak@<<<ip_address_elided>>>"]
You can connect to a specific node (whether in your riak_shell.config
or not) by typing 'connect "dev1@127.0.0.1";' substituting your
node name for dev1.

You may need to change the Erlang cookie to do this.

See also the 'reconnect' command.
Unhandled message received is {#Ref<0.0.0.135>,disconnected}

riak-shell(3)>
```

I have not changed the cookies during this process, and the cookie appears to be the same (at least in `/etc/riak/riak_shell.config`). (I am running the Riak TS AMI on AWS.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`riak-shell` runs in its own Erlang VM - entirely separate from the riak node

(You don't need to run `riak-shell` from the machine your node is on - it uses the normal `riak-erlang-client` to talk to `riak`)

If you you are on a Linux do `ps aux | grep riak_shell_app` it will give you the process number you need to kill that instance:

`08:30:45:~ $ ps aux | grep riak_shell_app
vagrant   4671  0.0  0.3 493260 34884 pts/4    Sl+  Aug17   0:03 /home/vagrant/riak_ee/dev/dev1/erts-5.10.3/bin/beam.smp -- -root /home/vagrant/riak_ee/dev/dev1 -progname erl -- -home /home/vagrant -- -boot /home/vagrant/riak_ee/dev/dev1/releases/2.1.1/start_clean -run riak_shell_app boot debug_off /home/vagrant/riak_ee/dev/dev1/bin/../log/riak_shell/riak_shell   -noshell -config /home/vagrant/riak_ee/dev/dev1/bin/../etc/riak`

I wrote a good chunk of it so let me know how you got on:
https://github.com/basho/riak_shell/graphs/contributors

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to verify that this works.